# Escalar tamaño de impresion Paginas Web

Tags: html, css

Quisiera hacerles una consulta. Estoy haciendo una web de toma de pedidos para mi emprendimiento. Ya esta todo listo pero ahora viene la parte de la impresion de las ordenes de pedido. Me gustaria se imprimieran ajustadas a un tamaño A5. De que manera se pueden configurar los estilos para escalarla a ese tamaño ??. Agradezco de antemano la valiosa informacion que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 0):

Las hojas A5 miden: 210 x 148 mm y en pixel: 2480 x 1748 px. La página web que quieres imprimir tendrá que medir la misma cantidad de pixeles. Aunque debes tomar en cuenta que cada quien imprimirá la página usando el tipo de hoja que configure en su navegador. Y que una cosa como esta puede afectar el utilizo del sitio a través de los diferentes dispositivos. Una solución podría ser la de generar una página para la impresión que herede de la página que el usuario desea imprimir y efectuar estas modificas en dicha página duplicada, así no se verá afectada la experiencia de usuario en tu sitio.

Como no proporcionas código, te doy una solución algo general:

```
<div style="max-height:2480px; max-width:1748px">
    <!-- tu página -->
</div>
```